# How can I create my own custom SortDefinition in MongDB C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting

I'm working with an application that features Kendo grid and a MongoDB database. The column sorting isn't working properly. The sorting is done on our backend. It's C# and we use the MongoDB C# driver.

I'm very new to MongoDB C# driver and SortDefinition. But I know that the code in our backend that handles the sorting is this:

```
        public async Task<QueryResult> ODataQueryAsync(string filter, string orderBy, int? skip, int? top, string @select = null, string expand = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var parser = oDataParserProvider.Get<TDto>(filter, orderBy, select, expand);
            var filterClause = parser.ParseFilter();
            var orderByClause = parser.ParseOrderBy();
            var filterDefinition = filterClause.GetFilterDefinition<TDto>();
            var sortDefinition = orderByClause.GetSortDefinition<TDto>();

            var query = Collection
                .Find(filterDefinition)
                .Sort(sortDefinition);
                
            ...
        }
```

The important lines are 1): `var parser = oDataParserProvider.Get<TDto>(filter, orderBy, select, expand)` which creates a parser based on the query data: `filter`, `orderBy`, `select`, and `expand`. 2): `var orderByClause = parser.ParseOrderBy()` which creates an orderByClause from the parser which simply contains the information about which field to sort by and whether it's ascending or descending. 3) `var sortDefinition = orderByClause.GetSortDefinition<TDto>()` which creates a SortDefinition out of orderByClause. And finally 4): `var query = Collection.Find(filterDefinition).Sort(sortDefinition)` which uses the SortDefinition to create/run the query.

There's also the GetSortDefinition() method which looks like this:

```
public static SortDefinition<T> GetSortDefinition<T>(this OrderByClause sort)
        {
            var visitor = new MongoDbQueryJsonNodeVisitor();
            var builder = new SortDefinitionBuilder<T>();
            var current = sort;
            var sortDefinitions = new List<SortDefinition<T>>();
            while (current != null)
            {
                var field = current.Expression.Accept(visitor);
                switch (current.Direction)
                {
                    case OrderByDirection.Ascending:
                        sortDefinitions.Add(builder.Ascending(field));
                        break;
                    case OrderByDirection.Descending:
                        sortDefinitions.Add(builder.Descending(field));
                        break;
                }
                current = current.ThenBy;
            }

            return builder.Combine(sortDefinitions);
        }
```

This seems to create SortDefinitions with only two pieces of information: the field to sort by and whether it's ascending or descending (just like the OrderByClause), and then combines them into one SortDefinition which is returned.

But there are columns in the grid that don't sort right. For example, we have a column whose data is numbers but its type is string, so the SortDefinitionBuilder sorts it alphabetically. We get the result:

```
1.08
1.09
12
13
2.01
```

^ For this case, is there a way to tell the SortDefinitionBuilder to sort numerically, or create a custom SortDefinition that sorts numerically?

There's also this:

```
006
011
AAA
BBB
CCC
#
(
+
-
0-001
0-002
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

^ This is the result of sorting a column alphabetically in ascending order. But the sorting seems to take numbers first, then upper case letter, then symbols (#, (, +, -), then numbers again (0-001, 0-002), and finally lower case letters. I have no idea what this sorting algorithm is doing. I'd like it to ignore case so the upper case and lower case letters aren't separated, and I'd like to move the symbols either to the beginning or end, not between upper case and lower case.

Things like this make me want to create my own sorting algorithm and give it to the SortDefinition or SortDefinitionBuilder. Is it possible to do this? Thanks.

Comment: With string data types having numbers - to sort by numbers you can try using the _Collation_ option.